# Simpler way to take the first N elements from a tuple?

Tags: elixir

I have a function that reduces a list of 3-element tuples, but when I'm done, I only need to return the first 2 elements. The pattern match here seems clunky. Is there a more elegant way to take the first N elements, something like `Enum.take/2` but for a tuple?

```
  def navigate(steps) do
    {x, y, _} = Enum.reduce(steps, {0, 0, 0}, &Navigator.do_step/2)
    {x, y}
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method out of the box, but one might use [`then/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#then/2) for that:

```elixir
steps
|> Enum.reduce({0, 0, 0}, &Navigator.do_step/2)
|> then(fn {a, b, _} -> {a, b} end)
```

Another way (I personally dislike it) would be to go through a list.

```elixir
steps
|> Enum.reduce({0, 0, 0}, &Navigator.do_step/2)
|> Tuple.to_list()
|> Enum.take(2)
|> List.to_tuple()
```

Also, in your case, you might use [`Tuple.delete_at/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Tuple.html#delete_at/2)

```elixir
steps
|> Enum.reduce({0, 0, 0}, &Navigator.do_step/2)
|> Tuple.delete_at(2)
```

---

`tuple_take/2` might be easily implemented as macro, btw:

```elixir
defmacro tuple_take({:{}, ctx, content}, count) do
  content = Enum.take(content, count)
  {:{}, ctx, content}
end
```